# I have this code but i dont know why it wont work can someone tell me?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<script>
var a = false;
function toggleBold(){
    a = !a;
    if(a){
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.fontWeight=700;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.fontWeight=200;
    }
}

var b = false;
function toggleitalic(){
    b = !b;
    if(b){
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.fontStyle="italic";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.fontStyle="normal";
    }
}

var c = false;
function toggleline() {
    c =!c;
    if(c){             
       document.getElementById("entertext").style.textDecoration="underline";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.textDecoration="none";
    }
}


var r = false;
function togglered() {
    console.log("clicked");
    r=!r;
    if(r){
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.color="red";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.color="black";
    }
}

var b = false;
function toggleblue() {
    console.log("clicked");

    b=!b;
    if(b){
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.color="blue";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.color="black";
    }
}

var g = false;
function togglegreen() {
    g=!g;
    if(g){
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.color="green";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.color="black";
    }
}

var imp = false;
function togglefontA(){
    imp = !imp;
    if(imp){
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.fontFamily= "Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";
    }
}


var tim = false;
function togglebfontB(){
    tim=!tim;
    if(tim){
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.fontFamily = "Times New Roman, Times, serif";
    }
}

var age = false;
function togglefontC(){
    age=!age;
    if(age){
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.fontFamily = "Agency FB, verdana, helvetica, sans-serif";
    }
}

var nor = false;
function togglefontD(){
    nor=!nor;
    if(nor){
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.fontFamily = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";
    }
}


function rgb(){
    if(check()){
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.backgroundColor =
            "rgb("+document.getElementById("red").value+","
            + document.getElementById("green").value+","
            + document.getElementById("blue").value+")";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("entertext").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}

function check(){
    var red= document.getElementById("red").value;
    var green= document.getElementById("green").value;
    var blue= document.getElementById("blue").value;
    return red <= 255 && red >= 0 && green <= 255 && green >= 0 && blue <=    255 && blue >= 0; 
}

   </script>
```

So the problem im having is that this code works on internet explorer on my personal laptop but not on chrome. on my uni computers the code does not work at all on chrome or on internet explorer. i have tried to go through the code looking for missplaced brackets but havent been able to find the problem. this has happend before and the problem was a missplaced or missing bracket. If someone could go through this code and tell me whats wrong or missing?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong about a piece of code *just* by looking at it, I would recommend that when it doesn't work, you open your browser's developer console and look for errors there; these are often very useful, and will either help you solve the problem yourself, or if you're not able to, help others see what the problem in your code might be and help you easier.

Comment: You would have an easier time finding missing brackets if you a) use a text editor which highlights the closing brackets/parenthesis for you (i.e. Sublime Text), and b) if you indent properly.

Comment: You haven't even said what the problem is. You need to debug it.

Comment: Wow, that is seriously some of the "wettest" code I've seen in a long time. Please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an *answer* per se, but here are some suggested improvements which limit the number of repeated bits of code, and doesn't have any global variables.

```
/* This only operates on the element with id="entertext". 
 * You could easily rewrite the function to pass in an element to 
 * operate on.  If no 3rd parameter is passed, it won't do anything if the
 * style is not equal to the first.
 */
function toggleStyle(property,ifTrueValue,ifFalseValue){
    var el = document.getElementById('entertext');
    if( el.style[property] !== ifTrueValue )
        el.style[property] = ifTrueValue;
    else if (typeof ifFalseValue !== 'undefined')
        el.style[property] = ifFalseValue;
    }
}

function toggleBold(){
    toggleStyle('fontWeight',700,200);
}

function toggleitalic(){
    toggleStyle('fontStyle','italic','normal');
}

function toggleline() {
    toggleStyle('textDecoration','underline','none');
}

function togglered() {
    toggleStyle('color','red','black');
}

function toggleblue() {
    toggleStyle('color','blue','black');
}

function togglegreen() {
    toggleStyle('color','green','black');
}

function togglefontA(){
    toggleStyle('fontFamily',"Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif")
}


function togglebfontB(){
    toggleStyle('fontFamily',"Times New Roman, Times, serif");
}

function togglefontC(){
    toggleStyle('fontFamily',"Agency FB, verdana, helvetica, sans-serif";
}

function togglefontD(){
    toggleStyle('fontFamily',"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif");
}


function rgb(){
    var rgb = getRGB()
        color;

    if( rgb == false)
        color = 'white';
    else
        color = "rgb("+rgb.red+","+rgb.green+","+rgb.blue+")";
    toggleStyle('backgroundColor', color );
}


function getRGB(){
    var red= document.getElementById("red").value;
    var green= document.getElementById("green").value;
    var blue= document.getElementById("blue").value;
    if( red <= 255 && red >= 0 && green <= 255 && green >= 0 && blue <= 255 && blue >= 0 ) {
        return {
            'red': red,
            'green': green,
            'blue': blue
        }
    } else 
        return false;
}
```